# Error when trying to validate In-app purchase at Google Play

Tags: php, google-api, in-app-purchase, google-api-php-client

I try to make a validation of purchases on the server, but it can't to make a request to Google Play Android Developer API. After a request it shows this one:

`Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/my.app.id/inapp/my_in_app_purchase/purchases/purchase_token: (403) Forbidden`

If I make a validation of this purchase by the test form in Developers Console, everything is OK and Google API would send a response.

Requests to other API (for example Books API) works fine.

To work with API I use [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Authorization goes by Service Account. In Developers Console access to Google Play Android Developer API is on.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your code? This looks similar (not identical) to my issue I posted today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323207/use-service-account-to-verify-google-inapppurchase

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution!

You must to connect your API with your app. You must go to your Google Play publish page (https://play.google.com/apps/publish) and invite a user with the service account email in Settings->User account & rights->Invite new user and give it the privileges of "View financial reports".

Thanks works for me, good luck!